# Why doesn't assigning a class to __getitem__ work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, python-3.6

Here is a `list` subclass which delegates its item getting to [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress).

```
from itertools import compress

class WeirdList(list):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return compress(self, item)

l = WeirdList([1, 2, 3, 4])
print(*l[0, 1, 0, 1]) # 2 4
```

The above works fine, although I was under the impression that I could directly assign `compress` to `__getitem__`.

```
class WeirdList(list):
    __getitem__ = compress

l = WeirdList([1, 2, 3, 4])
print(*l[0, 1, 0, 1])
```

This raises the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 7, in <module> print(*l[0, 1, 0, 1])
TypeError: Required argument 'selectors' (pos 2) not found
```

I believed this breaks because `compress` is a class and not a function, but the message shows the `TypeError` was raised from calling `compress`.

At which point did the `__getitem__` protcol call `compress` with a single argument?

Comment: The implicit adding of `self` as the first parameter only happens when retrieving a *function* from a class.

Comment: What Python version are you using, this is not the usual python 3 `TypeError: toto() missing 1 required positional argument: 'thing'` nor the python 2 `TypeError: toto() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`

Comment: @BenoîtPilatte This is 3.6.2 on Windows

Comment: @jasonharper Oh perfectly makes sense. This answers my question. Feel free to put write down an answer.

Comment: @jasonharper Not necessarily a function, but something with an appropriate `__get__` method (which `function` has).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function can be used as a method because it has a `__get__` attribute. The *class* `compress` doesn't have a `__get__` attribute:

```
>>> compress.__get__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
AttributeError: type object 'itertools.compress' has no attribute '__get__'
```

and so cannot be a method.

When invoking an attribute with a `__get__` method, the `__get__` method is called and its return value is returned, rather than the value of the attribute itself. That is, `l[0] == l.__getitem__(0) == l.__getitem__.__get__(l, type(l))(0)`, where the return value of `__get__` is an object that already has `l` passed to the function.

(If you've ever wondered what the `classmethod` and `staticmethod` decorators do, they return objects with different `__get__` methods.)

Comment: Class defining `__get__` method is called *descriptor*. Thorough description how it works is in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors).

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html also discusses how the descriptor protocol works.